# I have some with MySQL memory

Tags: mysql

No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

Comment: What's your imported file size ?

Comment: Question is unclear, please elaborate it.